# How to compile python code to WebAssembly without converting first to C

Tags: python, webassembly

today at work I was asked to find a solution to this problem:

- How can you compile python code to WebAssembly without first converting python to C?

I was not able to find a solution to that. I really hope that you guys can help me with that!

Every solution i found online was about converting python to C.

Comment: I haven't used it myself but RustPython is an interpreter written in Rust. One of the claims in the blurb is that it can be compiled into WebAssembly so that Python can be executed in the web browser. https://rustpython.github.io/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.